# How Do Modules Resolve A Constant's Scope?

Tags: ruby, module, scope

I've been reading this Ruby book, then there's this example that I haven't well understood :

```
CONST = "outer"
module Mod
    CONST = 1
    def Mod.method1
        # module method
        CONST + 1
    end
end
module Mod::Inner
    def (Mod::Inner).method2
        CONST + " scope"
    end
end
Mod::CONST  # => 1
Mod.method1 # => 2
Mod::Inner::method2 # => "outer scope"
```

Would you please explain this to me (a detailed explanation) so I can fully understand how the scope works in Ruby.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants in Ruby (identifiers beginning with a capital letter) are accessible based on the *lexical* scope in which they are defined/accessed.

In `method1`, the `CONST` within the `Mod` scope takes precedence over the outermost `CONST`. In `method2`, the `CONST` within the `Mod` scope is not visible lexically, so the outermost `CONST` is accessed.

As for the method definitions themselves, when the name is qualified with a preceding module constant (e.g. `Mod` or `Mod::Inner`), the method is defined as a "module method" rather than as an instance method of `self.class` (the default).

Names in the module/method hierarchy are separated by `::` or, alternatively in the case of the separator between the module and the module method, a `.`.

**Update**: Note that the reason why `Mod`'s constants are not visible to `method2` is that `Mod` was not separately "opened". The definition skipped directly to `Mod::Inner`. If the code were changed to:

```
module Mod
  module Inner
    def (Mod::Inner).method2
      ...
```

Then `Mod`'s constants would be accessible to `method2` and take precedence over any in the outer scope.

Comment: If I change the definition of `Inner` to `module Mod; module Inner; ...`, `CONST` is once again resolved as `Mod::CONST` even though it isn't in lexical scope. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You would find a good explanation on Ruby Constant lookup [here](http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup)

I would share code snippets with some explanation:

```
CONST = "outer"
module Mod
  CONST = 1
  def Mod.method1
    # module method
    Module.nesting # => [Mod]
    CONST + 1
  end
end
module Mod::Inner
  def (Mod::Inner).method2
    Module.nesting # => [Mod::Inner]
    CONST + " scope"
  end
end


Mod::CONST  # => 1
Mod.method1 # => 2
Mod::Inner::method2 # => "outer scope"
```

Have a look at the evaluation of `Module.nesting` above `(Mod::Inner).method2` looks in `Mod::Inner` as specified in the nesting for `CONST` which it does not find before it calls the main Object for `CONST`

In the example I have below, you would see that `Mod::Inner.method2` makes a call to Mod::Inner and then Mod to seek for `CONST` which it finds, so no need to call the `CONST` in Object

```
module Mod
  CONST = 1
  def Mod.method1
    Module.nesting # => [Mod]
    CONST + 1
  end

  module Inner
    def (Mod::Inner).method2
      Module.nesting # => [Mod::Inner, Mod]
      CONST.to_s + " scope"
    end
  end
end


Mod::CONST  # => 1
Mod.method1 # => 2
Object::CONST # => "outer"
Mod::Inner::method2 # => "1 scope"
```

When in doubt use nested class/constant definition over lexical, it would always do the right thing as expected

Comment: Is there any reason for this sort of behavior? It seems really confusing.

Comment: @Max it is advised to use the hierarchical definition over lexical, it would save you alot...