# rspec issue while testing two classes with the same name under different namespaces (modules)

Tags: ruby, rspec

Disclaimers:

- I'm pretty new to ruby
- Please don't ask me why I'm using the same class name in two different modules. I'm only trying to understand why rspec behaves this way; I found it confusing and could not find answers online.

Description of issue:

- I have two .rb files in /lib.
- Both have a class with the name
  FooClass, but under different modules (NamespaceOne, NamespaceTwo).
- Yet, when I run rspec, one test fails because it runs against the wrong class and the failure message looks weird, i.e. a part of the failure message implies that it's looking at NamespaceOne, while it's clear that it actually tried running the test against NamespaceTwo.

My question: Why does rspec behaves this way? What am I missing?

Here's what I have in the lib folder:

lib/one.rb:

```
module NamespaceOne

  class FooClass
    def self.method_one(input)
      1
    end
  end
end
```

lib/two.rb:

```
module NamespaceTwo

  class FooClass
    def self.method_two(input)
      2
    end
  end
end
```

, here are the two corresponding specs:

spec/one_spec.rb

```
require "one"

include NamespaceOne

describe FooClass do

    describe ".method_one" do
        context "given an empty string" do
            it "returns 1" do
                expect(FooClass.method_one("")).to eql(1)
            end
        end
    end

end
```

and spec/two_spec.rb

```
require "two"

include NamespaceTwo

describe FooClass do

    describe ".method_two" do
        context "given an empty string" do
            it "returns 2" do
                expect(FooClass.method_two("")).to eql(2)
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Finally, rspec output:

```
$ bundle exec rspec --format documentation

NamespaceOne::FooClass
  .method_one
    given an empty string
      returns 1 (FAILED - 1)

NamespaceTwo::FooClass
  .method_two
    given an empty string
      returns 2

Failures:

  1) NamespaceOne::FooClass.method_one given an empty string returns 1
     Failure/Error: expect(FooClass.method_one("")).to eql(1)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `method_one' for NamespaceTwo::FooClass:Class
       Did you mean?  method_two
     # ./spec/one_spec.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00201 seconds (files took 0.08006 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/one_spec.rb:9 # NamespaceOne::FooClass.method_one given an empty string returns 1
```

Note: In the tests/examples, if I call the method using the full namespace, the tests do pass. i.e the following tweaks in their respective spec files make the tests pass,

spec/one_spec.rb

```
expect(NamespaceOne::FooClass.method_one("")).to eql(1)
```

spec/two_spec.rb

```
expect(NamespaceTwo::FooClass.method_two("")).to eql(2)
```

but I don't understand why 'include'ing the modules as I did isn't enough.

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
require "one"

include NamespaceOne

describe FooClass do
```

you're including `NamespaceOne` in `Object`, but ruby doesn't know that the next namespace `FooClass` should resolve to `NamspaceOne`.  That's because it's done lexically (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20848317/3109182).  Instead use the full namespace when describing, that way rspec and ruby knows which constants to resolve to:

```
require "one"    
describe NamespaceOne::FooClass do
end
```